# Why does changing the type parameter of this class affect the scope of an inherited nested class?

Tags: java, jls

*Edit: people seem to have been thrown off by my typos and misuse of terminology. I've rewritten the question to address these concerns. Please forgive any further errors.*

I have a generic class `A` and two classes that extend it, `B` and `C`. `A`, `B`, and `C` have nested classes `X`, `Y`, and `Z` respectively. Both `Y` and `Z` try to extend `X` using only a simple type name in the superclass declaration. The only other difference between `B` and `C` is that `B` extends `A<Object>` while `C` extends `A<C.Z>`. For some reason, `X` is not in scope for the declaration of `Z`:

```
class A<T> {
    static class X {}
}

class B extends A<Object> {
    static class Y extends X {} // okay
}

class C extends A<C.Z> {
    static class Z extends X {} // error: X cannot be resolved to a type
}
```

This seems to be contrary to the scoping rules in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a declaration of a member m declared in or inherited by a class type C (§8.1.6) is the entire body of C, including any nested type declarations.

Why isn't `X` in scope for the declaration of `Z` when it is for `Y`? Is this specified in the JLS?

Comment: `Q` is _nested_ in `X`. `Y` _extends_ `X`. Therefore `X` is **not** a `Q`. So `B.Y.test` does not have an `int` argument. In your first example you call `B.Y.test` and in the second you call `B.Y.Q.test` - the generics are spurious.

Comment: I assumed the first block of code has a typo, and was intended to read `B.Y.Q.test()` and `B.Y.Q.test(0)`, like the second block has.

Comment: @VGR I wouldn't assume. There's quite some confusion here (multiple classes with the same name, really strange inheritance/nesting). It's best to try and get the OP to elucidate what the OP thinks this all does...

Comment: @BoristheSpider You should put an answer here.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo. I've edited it now. I retested the code in Eclipse and the errors are where I say they are.

Comment: Interestingly, the second example behaves like the first example if it is changed to `class B extends A<String>`.  I suspect the compiler hasn’t finished processing the declaration of `B` when it encounters `B.Y` (which it is forced to evaluate while in the midst of processing the `class B` declaration), so it uses the only unqualified `X` it knows about:  the top-level `class X`.

Comment: All this talk about "inner classes" and not one inner class in the example code.

Comment: @LewBloch `Z` is an inner class of `C`, no?

Comment: @slim Lew's comment applied to the previous edit and is technically correct. An inner class is a nested class that is neither explicitly nor implicitly static.